# Draw Shadow For Transparent Shape

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

I want to create only a shadow for certain shapes (without the object causing the shadow). For instance, for an ellipse:

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, offset, blur, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, drawInRect);
```

The shadow draws fine, but I'd like the shape to be transparent. I have tried setting the fill color to clear:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.clearColor.CGColor);
```

which causes the shadow to also be suppressed.

What is the easiest way to achieve a transparent shape with a black shadow? If I need to do a mask, how would I do that with Quartz?

**Edit:** As the first answerer has pointed out, the question was ambiguous or confusing. I've tried to clear that up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You want to see only the shadow, and none of the ellipse?

If you're drawing this with Quartz, this is tricky, because Quartz uses the ellipse's appearance to generate the shadow.  If you clip or mask the ellipse away, that will also affect the shadow.

One possibility is to adjust the shadow's offset, and the position of the ellipse, so that the ellipse is outside your context's visible area. For instance, if you were drawing in a 100 x 100 bitmap context, you could set your ellipse's position to {normalPosition.x - 100, normalPosition.y}, and increase the shadow's offset.x by 100. That way, the ellipse would be entirely out of the context, but the shadow would be in the same place.  (Adjust the math as necessary for your case, of course.)

Another alternative: if you use the `shadowPath` property on a CALayer, then the shadow is generated only based on that path, not on the layer's contents. It might be easier to manage that than pure CG, depending on your situation.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I'm still mucking around, but it SEEMS like if clip the ellipse away, the shadow still draws. I'll comment back when I know what I'm doing ;) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You'll have to post more code, I can't really guess exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Okay, posted my answer, above. Not sure how I figured out that EO stuff, but it's pretty nice...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with clipping paths. The EO stuff is necessary to define an outer space in which everything is drawn, and an inner space in which nothing is drawn.

I made this a tiny bit more complex because I'm putting in a light-colored red circle afterwards.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx); // store to ignore the clipping path later
    float margin = self.bounds.size.width * .1;
    CGRect ellipseRect = CGRectMake(margin, margin, self.bounds.size.width - 2*margin, self.bounds.size.height - 2*margin);

    // OUTER path is just the bounds
    CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.bounds, NULL);
    CGPathAddPath(mutablePath, NULL, pathRef);
    // INNER path is the same as the ellipse
    CGPathRef pathRef2 = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(ellipseRect, NULL);
    CGPathAddPath(mutablePath, NULL, pathRef2);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, mutablePath);
    CGContextEOClip(ctx);    

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.greenColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(margin/2.0f, margin/2.0f), 10, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, ellipseRect);

    // replace the green circle for a very transparent red one just for fun
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor.redColor colorWithAlphaComponent:.1].CGColor);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeZero, 0, NULL);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, ellipseRect);
}
```

Comment: I see, you wanted something different than what I thought. A picture would have helped. I thought you wanted an ellipse-shaped shadow (the whole thing), but instead what you got is an ellipse-shaped shadow with an ellipse cut out of it. Also there's some green antialiasing artifacts around the ellipse.

Comment: Hi Kurt, sorry I didn't make the question clearer. I'd just delete the whole thing, but since I (and someone else) upvoted you, this'll be one for the history books :)

Comment: No worries, either effect could be useful in different situations.